# Dynamic Env Variables for Node

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

So I'm trying to think of a solution to select specific npm's env variables for instance:

```
process.env.LOCATIONS_HOST
 or 
process.env.SOME_OTHER_API_HOST

Then I can write a function to get that like

getSpecificHost(name) {
 return process.env.name
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `process.env[name]` where name is a string.

Comment: Hmm I thought I tried that but it didn't work I'll give it another shot thans @dan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: @DanD. that doesnt work for me, its undefined. I created a post regarding this issue. Maybe you can help out.

Comment: @beeftony Are you sure that the environment variable is actually set? Is it included in the output of `env`?

Comment: Yes, process.env['MIX_VARIABLE_NAME'] works process.env[variable] where variable = 'MIX_VARIABLE_NAME' doesnt.